How to copy a file to the clipboard from the command line for pasting it into web page upload fields?
Is there a way to copy a file to the clipboard from the command line so that I can paste it into a web page's upload area using Ctrl+V? I’m looking for a solution that mimics the behavior of file managers like Dolphin, Nautilus, or Nemo when I press Ctrl+C on a file, but executed from the terminal.
In GUI file managers, pressing Ctrl+C on a file copies it as a "file object", and pasting with Ctrl+V into a web page upload field directly uploads the file.
I tried replicating this GUI behavior with xclip by copying the absolute path with a file:// prefix:
echo -n "file:///path/to/file.txt" | xclip -selection clipboard

However, this approach doesn’t work for file upload in browsers, it only pastes the path as text. How can I mimic the Dolphin, Nemo and Nautilus clipboard behavior when I copy files from them? But using the command line instead?

Example
Let's say I have a file called file.txt in a folder and I'm using Dolphin (it works the same for Nemo or Nautilus)

This file content is:
# Hello World File

This is a file with a content, it has any number of lines.

Now let's say I select this file and press Ctrl+C in it, if I try to paste it in a text editor I'll see
file:///home/Dados/question/file.txt
Well, even though it looks like it's just copying the absolute path of the file, it's actually doing something more. Let's say I open the ChatGPT prompt and press Ctrl+V in it:

It uploads it there as a file, not the absolute path of the file. That's what I'd like to do... However, using xclip or xsel with:
echo -n "file:///path/to/file.txt" | xclip -selection clipboard
or
printf '/path/to/file.txt' | xclip -sel c
These commands don't work as I expect, if I use them and press Ctrl+V on ChatGPT it'll just paste the absolute path of the file:

This behavior is different from the behavior of Dolphin, Nemo and Nautilus when I copy files with them... My main goal is to create a script that will get the clipboard content, create a temporary file, and then save it as a file on the clipboard, something like:
file_content="$(xclip -out -selection clipboard)"
file="$(mktemp)"
echo "$file_content" > "$file"
command-that-saves-file-as-object "$file"

Doing this allows me to attach this script to a shortcut, then I can quickly upload content to ChatGPT as files. I could manually open a file, paste the text to it, and then upload it there, but I want to optimize this process, and for that I need a way of doing what Dolphin, Nautilus and Nemo do when I copy a file from them.

To summarize copying text: if you use gnome-terminal in Ubuntu Desktop, then you can use the following: 1. Mark the text, that you want to paste by pressing the left mouse button and move the mouse; 2. Press shift + ctrl + c to 'Copy' (to clipboard). 3. Paste into the GUI application's input text box with ctrl +c. But if you want to 'upload a file', and it doesn't work with the file name as text, then you can start the file browser with the command nautilus . in the current directory and use nautilus to drag and drop the file into the 'upload area'.

Could you clarify what you mean by "pasting with CTRL+V into a web page upload field directly uploads the file"? A plain upload form is usually comprised of two buttons ("Select file" / "Upload"), there's no section where you could paste something in. Are you referring to a specific (custom) form? If so can you post a link to the form?

But anyways all that hitting CTRL + C on a file on Nautilus seems to do is to copy the raw path to the clipboard selection, so you could try just printf '/path/to/file.txt' | xclip -sel c

@kos & sudodus I've updated the question with an example of my use case and clarified my main goal. Even though it seems that Nautilus just copies the raw path to the clipboard selection, that's not the only thing that it's doing, it's doing something else.

Hmm I see what you mean; I'm not too familiar with what's happening but now I'm curious, I'll try and get back at this tomorrow, I'm wondering what's going on behind the scenes

See at: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53537/70524

@muru Thanks, the problem was partially solved with this command: echo "file:///path/to/file.txt" | xclip -selection clipboard -t 'text/uri-list', but even though it works perfectly fine for pasting in Firefox. It doesn't work at all in Google Chrome. Since most of the time I use Chrome that's still an issue in my case.

Maybe try the x-special/gnome-copied-files format described there
